# How to capture the values in a row

Tags: php

I have a dynamic table and I want to make sure when the delete button is pressed, you have to remove the corresponding values ​​in the table of the database.

Comment: Do you have your codes so that we can see?

Comment: If it's dynamic, show us the PHP that is generating the table.

Comment: it's a simple generator of tr and td... nothing of special

Comment: NB: Image is no longer available.

Comment: @Cœur Good eyesight! Thanks.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 I've reported the bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317953/infrequent-data-corrupting-bug-when-writing-values

Answer (score 0):

You must fetch the id using the code below and an anchor tag to refer to **your_script.php** that process the deletion associated with the variable id that contains the id of data

```
$query  =   mysqli_query($your_connection, "SELECT * FROM your_table") or exit(mysqli_error);

while($rows =mysqli_fetch_array($query)):   //fetch data from the table

   $id      =   $rows['id'];                //get id of specific data 
   $product =   $rows['product']; 
   $seller  =   $rows['seller']; 
   $quant   =   $rows['quantity']; 
   $price   =   $rows['price']; 


   echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $product . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

   echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $seller  . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

   echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $quant   . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

   echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $price   . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";


   //anchor tag href to your_script.php with the variable $id attached to it then use javascript to confirm delete or not
   echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>     
            <a href=\"your_script.php?id=$id\" onClick=\"javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product?')\">Delete</a> <td>";
            echo </td> ";           
   echo "</tr>";

endwhile;
```

Comment: but when i catch the data, i must execute a query for deleting the value

Comment: @JackIlPazzo ofcourse you should. That's what I emphasize (your_script.php). You cannot delete a record without executing a query deleting it

Comment: in: "your_script.php? do I enter? 
The page that I run the query I suppose.

Comment: @JackIlPazzo Yes you need to enter the query that deletes the data

Comment: Ok thanks :) ultimate question:

why i get this error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, resource given

Comment: @JackIlPazzo $query inside the mysqli_fetch_array should be a result from e.g. $query = mysqli_query($your_connection, "SELECT * FROM your_table") or exit(mysqli_error()); NOTE: use mysqli not mysql all through out your codes. CHANGE your_connection and your_table

Comment: this is the line: while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

Comment: Yes, but she did not understand, from the image I posted, for example by pressing the delete button next to the value "30", the one on the first row. 
You must be able to automatically delete the entire row by executing a query, and then from my table in the db will disappear HardDisk, amazon, 1, 30.

Comment: @JackIlPazzo You must research more then. I can't give you all codes in here

Comment: ther's a tutorial for this?